# svg content exceeds element

Tags: html, css, svg

The SVG Image is not displayed properly. I expect the "::before" to be 18x18px and the SVG to be displayed exactly the way it looks.
[image]
If you open the SVG in a new TAB it's exactly 18x18 px.
[image]

Why does it move outside the container in the example?
Am I doing something wrong?

```css
.row {
  background-color: red; 
}
.col-12 {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.marketing {
    font-weight: 800;
}
.marketing .headline {
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem 10%;
}
.arrow::before {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"></path></svg>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 marketing p-0">
    <div class="headline">
      <span class="p-2 bg-white arrow">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `display:inline-block;  width:18px; height:18px;` for the before

Comment: result doesn't change when I add those to the arrow class.

Comment: As I've commented: add it to the before: `.arrow::before`

Comment: I added all three to ```.arrow::before``` and it didn't change anything (https://jsfiddle.net/4ra3dwy8/2/). When I add a fourth class ```vertical-align``` then you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, shape in your icon itself is shifted up in the viewBox, if you expected to see it centred within square, you might have been misled:

[image]

Then, as @enxaneta suggested in the comment, making it inline-box and setting dimensions should help, just make sure you use proper vertical-align.

```css
.row {
  background-color: red; 
}
.col-12 {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.marketing {
    font-weight: 800;
}
.marketing .headline {
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem 10%;
}
.arrow::before {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"></path></svg>');
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 marketing p-0">
    <div class="headline">
      <span class="p-2 bg-white arrow">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Simplified test-cases without align:

```css
.original::before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg \
  width="18" \
  height="18" \
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5 5"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lime" stroke="green" opacity=".7"/></svg>');
}

.fixed::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg \
  width="18" \
  height="18" \
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5 5"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lime" stroke="green" opacity=".7"/></svg>');
}
/* demonstrative: */
span::before { background-color: red; outline: 1px solid blue; }
span::after { content: ' ' attr(class); }
html { background: dimgrey; color: snow;  }
```

```html
<span class="original"></span>

<hr>

<span class="fixed"></span>
```

(I was misled about observation that presence of dimension in SVG affect it's align.)

Comment: I didn't knew the Icon was not fully centered within it's viewport. But you understood what my goal was. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: [quote] just make sure you use proper vertical-align. [/quote] that was the point I was missing. Because just adding those three classes didn't worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/4ra3dwy8/2/ and I wonder why does it work on your small example without vertical-align? For me just adding display, width and height didn't changed anything. Would love to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

1. Alignment works best when setting the `.arrow` span to `display: inline-flex`. Then, align the SVG with `stretch` and the text with `center`.
2. The arrow grafic is not correctly aligned inside the SVG. Change the `viewBox` attribute value to `0 0 18 16`. As a side note, none of the attributes `height`, `fill="currentColor"` and `class` will have any effect.

```css
.row {
  background-color: red; 
}
.col-12 {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.marketing {
    font-weight: 800;
}
.marketing .headline {
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem 10%;
}
.arrow {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 2.2rem;
    align-items: center;
}
.arrow::before {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" viewBox="0 0 18 16"><path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"></path></svg>');
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 marketing p-0">
    <div class="headline">
      <span class="p-2 bg-white arrow">
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach at first. If I remember correctly I did all on the ```.arrow::before``` and not the way you did it. What made me try different ways is that display always showed that note https://imgur.com/a/7lFHwxV and I assumed I'm doing something wrong. But thank you for your solution. Appreciate it.